# For what values do these parametric equations draw a circle in the clockwise direction?

Tags: parametric

So I've got this set of parametric equation on the x-y plane

$x=cos(ln(5t))$

$y=sin(ln(5t))$

for $t>0$. I need to find the range of values for which the circle is drawn in the clockwise direction. Initially I tried for values where $t>0.2$ and $0>t>0.2$, but neither of these worked. I also tried for t values within $\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}e^\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{5}e^\frac{3\pi}{2}$, but these didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Sine and cosine trace out the unit circle when the parameter varies from $0$ to $2\pi$. What values of $t$ make $\ln(5t)$ equal $0$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: neither  for $t<0.2$, $t>0.2$, nor $t<\frac{1}{5}e^({2\pi})$, $t>\frac{1}{5}e^(2\pi)$ works.